# How do I make a field required when submitting an issue in Mantis?

Tags: mantis

I am running Mantis 1.2.11 and want to enforce certain fields (in addition to the default required) to be filled out before submitting a new issue. After searching for a while and looking in the [manual](http://www.mantisbt.org/manual/manual.configuration.php), I haven't been able to find out how to configure this.

Does Mantis just not support configuring required fields (short of modifying the source code)?

Comment: Which fields do you want to make required?

Comment: My immediate needs are the ***Product Version*** field, but I may want  other fields in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the way to go is to implement a custom function according to this forum thread:
https://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=20740

https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide.html#ADMIN.CUSTOMIZE.CUSTOMFUNCS